"async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression"
When I do !unban.
The bot will say this: An error occurred:
Command raised an exception: TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression
Trying to do a unban system for the bot to unban a person.
class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name="ban")
    @has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def ban(self, ctx, member: Member, *, reason=None):
        """Ban a member from the server"""
        try:
            await member.ban(reason=reason)
            await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been banned for: {reason}')
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f'Failed to ban {member.mention}: {e}')

    @ban.error
    async def ban_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("You don't have the permission to ban members.")



    @commands.command(name="unban")
    @has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def unban(self, ctx, *, member):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
            banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
            member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

            for ban_entry in banned_users:
                user = ban_entry.user

                if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
                    await ctx.guild.unban(user)


Your question title should identify the specific error so other people can accurately tell whether answers to your question are likely to help with their questions as well. Think of Stack Overflow as a giant FAQ, not a discussion forum: the primary goal is to build a knowledge base of question-and-answer pairs that will help other people; getting your own questions answered is just a happy side effect.

That said, you probably want an async for, not an await. Can't really say with much more certainty where the problem is happening since you aren't giving us a stack trace.

(Insofar as that is the problem, it's arguably already asked and answered over at What is an async generator & how is it different from a coroutine in Python?)

Your line: banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans() is incorrect, as the bans method returns an asynchronous iterator, rather than asynchronously returning a list.
Try:
banned_users = ctx.guild.bans()      # don't await here, `bans()` is not a coroutine
...

async for ban_entry in banned_users: # instead, use `async for` here
   ...

You could combine the two lines, but there's no need to do so.

@CharlesDuffy Yep, that was a silly typo I fixed, and then made a second time.
